# Why Hive will search its configuration profile in HADOOP_CONF_DIR first?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Today I found that if I copy `hive-site.xml` into `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/`, Hive will use the `hive-site.xml` in the `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/` instead of the one in `$HIVE_HOME/conf`, and it will also search for the `hive-log4j.properties` in `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/`.
If not found, Hive will just use the default one in `/lib/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.7.6.jar!/hive-log4j.properties` instead of the customized one in `$HIVE_HOME/conf`, but why?

I searched the keyword *copy hive-site.xml to HADOOP_HOME* in the official Hive manual in apache.org but failed to find any explanation...

My Hive version is hive-1.1.0-cdh5.7.6, Hadoop version hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.7.6, JDK 1.7.

Comment: Check out the `hadoop classpath` command

Comment: @cricket_007 it's like `/opt/cdh-5.7.6/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.7.6/etc/hadoop:/opt/cdh-5.7.6/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.7.6/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/cdh-5.7.6/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.7.6/share/hadoop/common/*`.... but why it's related to my problem?

Comment: Because `/opt/cdh-5.7.6/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.7.6/etc/hadoop:` is the very first item in the classpath. Therefore, the first occurrence of that xml file is gathered

Comment: Not sure why you're copying around xml files. Let cloudera manager do the configuration

Comment: @cricket_007 So you are implying that Hive searches Hadoop classpath first for its configuration files and dependent jars instead of its own folder?

Comment: Hive, Spark, Pig, Hbase, etc. Yes, they all rely on the Hadoop classpath

Comment: @cricket_007 Because when I use sqoop, I have to copy `hive-site.xml` into `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or it will give errors... So my teacher told me to do so... But this kind of behavior is never documented in the Apache documentation so I was still quite confused...It's like magic...  I will check out Cloudera manager, thanks!

Comment: You're using `cdh5.7.6`, a Cloudera installation, not vanilla Hadoop. You should already have Cloudera Manager... Anyways, I'm pretty sure you can add hive-site.xml to sqoop via a `--files` flag, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've mentioned Sqoop, therefore I'll point out the proper processes for getting hive XML configuration.

1) There's a classpath problem if the file isn't found. Copying the file is one solution, but a poor one. A symlink is preferred.
Every time I've used Sqoop, I never messed around with controlling any XML files - it just worked. Therefore, both HDP and CDH must have the proper classpath and/or symlinks setup.

2) The documentation states where configurations are loaded from

> Sqoop will fall back to $HADOOP_HOME. If it is not set either, Sqoop will use the default installation locations for Apache Bigtop, /usr/lib/hadoop and /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce, respectively.
>
> The active Hadoop configuration is loaded from $HADOOP_HOME/conf/, unless the $HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable is set

This classpath controls where configurations are loaded from

3) You can also, at runtime, give extra files

> -files `<comma separated list of files>`    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster

```
sqoop import -files $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml ...
```